# ZipOutputStream - zipping files with wrong content

Tags: java, zip, zipoutputstream

i can zipping files, but with wrong content ... for example - content in a.txt:

```
!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~€‚„…†‡‰Š‹ŚŤŽŹ‘’“”•–—™š›śťžź ˇ˘Ł¤Ą¦§¨©Ş«¬­®Ż°±˛ł´µ¶·¸ąş»Ľ˝ľżŔÁÂĂÄĹĆÇČÉĘËĚÍÎĎĐŃŇÓÔŐÖ×ŘŮÚŰÜÝŢßŕáâăäĺćçčéęëěíîďđńňóôőö÷řůúűüýţ`
```

This is code for zipping file:

```
void zipping() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("C:\\...\\newZip.zip");
        ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(os);

        File folder = new File("C:\\...\\A");

        for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
            //ZipEntry ze2 = new ZipEntry(fileEntry.getPath());
            //zos.putNextEntry(ze2);
            zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(fileEntry.getName()));
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
                zos.write(i);
            }
        }
        zos.close();
    }
```

Where is bug? Thanks for help.

Comment: I didn't understand the use of `for` loop here!!!

Comment: what is  the bug? Can you please share some more details ?

Comment: "C:\\...\\newZip.zip" is not a valid filename

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are writing bytes into the zip file, starting from 1 to 10000. So depending on the encoding used, the output you have shown is correct.

Maybe you should read from the files you want to zip. Below is the code modified from yours.

```
void zipping(File file) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("C:\\...\\newZip.zip");
        ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(os);

        File folder = new File("C:\\...\\A");

        for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {

            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(fileEntry);
            zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(fileEntry.getName()));

            // buffer size
            byte[] b = new byte[1024];
            int count;

            // Read from file and write to zip file
            while ((count = in.read(b)) > 0) {
                zos.write(b, 0, count);
            }
        }    

        zos.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code like this -

```
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("C:\\newZip.zip");
    ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(os);

    File folder = new File("C:\\zipit");
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
        zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(fileEntry.getName()));
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(fileEntry.getAbsoluteFile());
        int len=0;
        while ((len = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            zos.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
    }
    zos.close();
```